# how to concatenate bit with a string in system verilog?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, vlsi

```
if(ci.busy) begin// writing
    **dataout** = {dataout,string'(**ci.dout**)};
    $sformat( request,"%b",req.dout );
    $fwrite(data, request);
end
```

here ci.dout is bit and dataout is string.
This is the code I was using to convert bit to string using static casting. But the output of dataout at the end of test is 0. I would really appreciate help.

Comment: It would help to show the values used for the variables and expected results.

Answer (score 3):

Casting with `string'()` will use `ci.dout` as the ASCII code of a string. For example, `string'(8'h41)` is "A", and `string'(88'h48656C6C6F20576F726C64)` is "Hello World"

Any of the following will work for you:

1. `dataout = {dataout,$sformatf("%b", ci.dout)};`
2. `dataout = $sformatf("%s%b", dataout, ci.dout);`
3. `$sformat(dataout, "%s%b", dataout, ci.dout);`